# Spring Batch Job for truncate table

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-bean

I have a two step in my Job
Step 1-->Truncate data from table A
Step 2--> Read from different datasource and insert data into table A

In Step 1 initialization of writer bean is throwing the exception, below is the code of writer bean and exception.

```
        @Bean
    public ItemWriter truncateData() {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter();
        writer.setSql("TRUNCATE TABLE A"); 
        writer.setDataSource(dwhDataSource);
        return writer;
    }
```

Exception:-

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'truncateData' defined in class path resource Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Using SQL statement with '?' placeholders requires an ItemPreparedStatementSetter
```

Please let me know if you need more information and i'm doing any wrong in creating the bean.

Comment: Why you are using JdbcBatchItemWriter to execute a truncate table query? It is not a correct one. JdbcBatchItemWriter  is expecting one or multiple objects which are returned from Reader or Processor to write (such as INSERT query) to database. It is NOT designed to execute a generic query.

Comment: For step 1 use a Tasklet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tasklet to delete a table in spring batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834304/tasklet-to-delete-a-table-in-spring-batch)

Comment: Thanks @NghiaDo for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: thanks @LucaBassoRicci sample code in the url perfectly worked for me.

Comment: yw. Up vote linked answer if you found it useful