# Difference between Step, Tasklet and Chunk in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

What is the difference between Step, Tasklet and Chunk in spring batch.?

Also, How to execute step in parallel via Spring Batch. ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Well that's actually a good question. Here's an example of configuration:

```
<job id="sampleJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <step id="step1" next="step2">
        <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="10"/>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
    <step id="step2">
         <tasklet ref="myTasklet"/>
    </step>
</job>
```

You have a Job, this job is made of steps. Most of the time, these steps are successive. You define in what order your work must be done with steps: you do step 1, then step 2, then step 3, you can do step 4 if step 3 failed, or go directly to step 5, etc.

What is done in the Step is represented by a tasklet, they do the task.

In spring batch, you'll mostly do chunk oriented processing: with a reader, a processor, and a writer. From the official documentation:

> Chunk oriented processing refers to reading the data one at a time,
>   and creating 'chunks' that will be written out, within a transaction
>   boundary

But you can make your own tasklet, and set it in your step. For example, a tasklet that executes a SQL query. (example here: [Tasklet to delete a table in spring batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834304/tasklet-to-delete-a-table-in-spring-batch) )

So, the steps are ordered in a job, each step contains a tasklet, which does a task. One of those tasklet (and probably the most used one) is the chunk oriented processing tasklet.

If you're curious, here is the [ChunkOrientedTasklet's doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/item/ChunkOrientedTasklet.html). As you can see, it implements the `Tasklet` interface.

For more information:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html

And yes, spring batch is well made for parrallel processing, using flows: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html