# Spring Batch - Read query from file and execute it on database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I know I can simply read the file straight from step1, a moment before setting the sql query into the reader, but I want to keep the process of reading the query separate from database reading.

Here is my job configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration {

    [...]

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Map<String, Object>> dynamicSqlItemReader() {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<Map<String, Object>> jir = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        jir.setSql((String) contextHolder.getContext().get("fileContent"));
        jir.setDataSource(dataSource);
        jir.setRowMapper(new ColumnMapRowMapper());
        return jir;
    }

    private FlatFileItemReader<String> flatFileItemReader() {
        [...]
    }

    private ItemWriter<? super String> sysoItemWriter() {
        return (ItemWriter<String>) list -> {
            for (String element : list) {
                System.out.println(element);
            }
            contextHolder.getContext().put("fileContent", list.get(0));
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Map<String, Object>> customerItemWriter() {
        return list -> {
            for (Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap : list) {
                System.out.println(stringObjectMap);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step0() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step0")
                .<String, String>chunk(1)
                .reader(flatFileItemReader())
                .writer(sysoItemWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Map<String, Object>, Map<String, Object>>chunk(10)
                .reader(dynamicSqlItemReader())
                .writer(customerItemWriter())
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step0())
                .next(step1())
                .build();
    }
}
```

This throws a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The SQL query must be provided` because the `contextHolder.getContext().get("fileContent")` is still `null` at time of setting the query.

Comment: What is the db query doing?

Comment: I don't know a priori: path to sql query is going to be a batch parameter. But basically they are `select`.

Comment: which contextHolder are you using?

Comment: It's a bean of mine containing a Map<String, Object>.

Answer (score 0):

Before step1, you could write a tasklet for building the query and putting it into context, so that it stays separate and also it becomes available to step1. See more about tasklet here: [Tasklet to delete a table in spring batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834304/tasklet-to-delete-a-table-in-spring-batch)

Comment: I also tried using a tasklet, but the problem is still there.     `@Bean
    public Step step0() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step0")
                .tasklet((stepContribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    File f = new File("D:\\query.sql");
                    contextHolder.getContext().put("fileContent", FileUtils.readFileToString(f, "UTF-8"));
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You are not using your created `contextHolder` properly that's why the value there is null.

Make sure you are putting your data in `flatFileItemReader()` in `contextHolder` in directly as a map because when you are getting value, you are using `contextholder.getContext()`. Since it's an simple map,not a `ApplicationContext`, the method you are using does not exist.